# Missing configuration builder class when using the Security bundle without a Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the `symfony/security-bundle` as a standalone composer package. This is not part of a Symfony application. Just the package itself.

I've added the package via composer by doing `composer require symfony/security-bundle`.

My `composer.json` file looks like this

```
{
    ...
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "9.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.4",
        "symfony/config": "^5.4",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.10",
        "symfony/cache": "^5.4",
        "twig/twig": "3.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^5.4"
    }
}
```

Please note that I've removed some parts for the sake of keeping the `composer.json` file listed here short.

I'm trying to set up a very simple firewall using the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.x/security.html#the-firewall). I'm using the PHP configuration, not the YAML or XML one.

I have copy + pasted the documentation example straight into my project

```
// config/packages/security.php
use Symfony\Config\SecurityConfig;

return static function (SecurityConfig $security) {
    // ...
    $security->firewall('dev')
        ->pattern('^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/')
        ->security(false)
    ;

    $security->firewall('main')
        ->lazy(true)

        // activate different ways to authenticate
        // https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        // https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        // ->switchUser(true)
    ;
};
```

The issue that I'm having is that `Symfony\Config\SecurityConfig` class simply doesn't exist.

[image]

I've tried redownloading the packages. Clearing composer cache. Manually downloading the security bundle too.

---

- Do I need to install another package?
- Is this a bug in the docs? If so, do I have any options to make this work?

Comment: I've edited the question to include all the packages and autoload stuff. Those are not the issue. I have other packages that work fine.

Comment: Using the bundle or the package itself makes no difference since the bundle is just a collection of packages(security core + security http + security csrf + security-guard = security). Also configBuilders must come with the package otherwise there's no point. They're used by the dependency injection package(if installed) or any other DI packge available if configured.

Comment: @Andrei Just wanted to point out that your understanding of bundles is wrong. An actual bundle package contains code specifically for the framework. Other packages will be installed as dependencies.  As already mentioned the SecurityConfig class is created by the framework as part of the build process. The firewall itself requires it to be "plugged" into a request/response processor.  It will take some effort to use standalone.

Comment: @Cerad that's correct. My understanding of bundles was wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug in the documentation, that article is meant to be used to understand the Symfony Bundle within a Symfony application. Which makes senses, since "bundles" are by definition Symfony packages, with many pieces that are meant to be tied together by the Framework bundle. What makes a "package" into a "bundle" is precisely the framework integration.

In this case, the specifics of the `Symfony\Config\SecurityConfig` "missing" class... that class is built by the Framework bundle during container compilation. They **do not** come with the bundle, as explained [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-config-builder-classes):

> These classes **are generated automatically in your project build directory** and transform your bundle configuration classes into fluent interface classes with methods named after your config option

(Emphasis mine).

Without the framework bundle, those classes are simply not generated. And they do not exist [in the original source](https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/tree/5.4), as one can easily verify.

If you want to use these packages outside a Symfony application, you'll have to deal with the configuration yourself. You may want to check [this article](https://wouterj.nl/2019/03/understanding-symfony-security-by-using-it-standalone), that you may find useful.